# Looping through returned rows of dataset in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, loops, dataset

I have an application written in VB.Net which shows data from a table in a gridview.

```
 Dim DbaseDataSet As DreamApp.DbaseDataSet = CType(Me.FindResource("DbaseDataSet"), DreamApp.DbaseDataSet)
    Dim DbaseDataSetDevicesTableAdapter As DreamApp.DbaseDataSetTableAdapters.DevicesTableAdapter = New DreamApp.DbaseDataSetTableAdapters.DevicesTableAdapter()
    DbaseDataSetDevicesTableAdapter.Fill(DbaseDataSet.Devices)
    Dim DevicesViewSource1 As System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource = CType(Me.FindResource("DevicesViewSource1"), System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)
    DevicesViewSource1.View.MoveCurrentToFirst()
```

Query which returns values is:

```
SELECT [Name], [Username], [Password], [IP], [Type], [Curr] FROM [Devices]
```

My table is filled with correct data. 
How would i iterate through rows that are returned to make for each loop, and to run a piece of code for each returned row using returned values from a query above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just loop over `Rows` property

```
For each drRow as Datarow in DbaseDataSet.Devices.Rows

....
'DrRow("colname") = something

Next
```

Comment: Tank you Sir! appreciated